# Add new attribute in JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have the following scenario

```
"sections": [
      {
        "id": XXXX,
        "tipology": "TIPOLOGY"
      },
      {
        "id": XXXX,
        "tipology": "TIPOLOGY"
      },
      {"num": 2}
    ],
```

I'm using JSONArray and JSONObject. Is there some way to do this?

```
"sections": [
      "num": 2,
      {
        "id": XXXX,
        "tipology": "TIPOLOGY"
      },
      {
        "id": XXXX,
        "tipology": "TIPOLOGY"
      },

    ],
```

Comment: Think about what that would mean: the array itself would have an attribute. As you should be able to see that's not something JSON specifies (in fact in most languages arrays can't have additional attributes). Thus you'd have to either use option 1 or make "sections" an object that has the field "num" _and_ the array next to it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to count the array within. I think you can do it below way.

```
{
    "sections": [{
            "id": "XXXX",
            "tipology": "TIPOLOGY"
        },
        {
            "id": "XXXX",
            "tipology": "TIPOLOGY"
        }
    ],
    "num": 2
}
```

OR

```
{
"sections": [{
        "id": "XXXX",
        "tipology": "TIPOLOGY"
    },
    {
        "id": "XXXX",
        "tipology": "TIPOLOGY"
    }, {
        "id": "COUNT",
        "num": 2
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Thats right! But i need that num attribute is like i'm posted

Comment: The way you mentioned is not possible in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the json object in the following format, hope it works for you.

{
    "sections": {
        "num": 100,
        "values": [{
            "id": "XXXX",
            "tipology": "TIPOLOGY"
        }]
    }
}

And the java code for the above program is below.

```
import org.json.*;

class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject sections = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        obj.put("num", new Integer(2));
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject value = new JSONObject();
        value.put("id", "XXXX");
        value.put("tipology", "TIPOLOGY");

        array.put(value);
        obj.put("values", array);

        sections.put("sections", obj);
        System.out.print(sections);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @ABHISHEK HONEY but values attribute should not be present

Comment: But that is not the correct json format. You can try it in any json formatter, it will tell that it is not the correct json format. Can I know why you want it in that format only?